# PowerShell Active Directory import script failing with PS 3.0 or above

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I don't know much about PowerShell but have inherited a script from someone who is no longer available for assistance. This script imports AD Group Info and memberships related to Users and Computers. It works fine when run on a machine with PS 2.0 but it crashes if executed on PS 3.0 or newer.

I have not been able to figure out what needs to be modified but it seems the errors start occurring in the "Computer" membership import step and there are hundreds of errors that all say:

**Command failed while processing computers: , Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown**

Then at some point it looks like the script just stops and it never even gets to the 3rd step / function.

Any advice?

```
[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.DirectoryServices") | Out-Null

$DBServer = "DBSERVER"
$DBName = "DBNAME"
$TableUsers = "[$DBName].[dbo].[AD_GroupToClient]"
$TableComps = "[$DBName].[dbo].[AD_GroupToDevice]"
$TableGroups = "[$DBName].[dbo].[AD_Group_Info]"
$sqldateformat = "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss:fff"

[system.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection]$global:SqlConnection = $null

function Get-ScriptPath { $Invocation = (Get-Variable MyInvocation -Scope 1).Value; Split-Path $Invocation.MyCommand.Path }
$ScriptPath = Get-ScriptPath
$Logfile = "$ScriptPath\OutLog.log"

function Write-Logfile {
param($logtext)
[string](Get-Date -format $sqldateformat) + "`t$logtext" | Out-File $Logfile -Encoding ascii -Append
}

function Open-Database {
$global:SqlConnection = New-Object system.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection 
try {
    $global:SqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Server=$DBServer;Database=$DBName;Integrated Security=True"
    $global:SqlConnection.Open() | Out-Null
    Write-Logfile "OK`tDatabase opened"
} catch {
    Write-Host "Error Opening SQL Database`t$($_.Exception.Message)"
    Write-Logfile "Error`tDatabase open failed, $($_.exception.message)"
    exit
}
}

function Close-Database {
$global:SqlConnection.Close()
Write-Logfile "OK`tDatabase closed"
}

function Esc-Quote {
param($str)
if ($str) { $str.Replace("'","''") }
}

 function Run-DBCommand {
 param($SqlCommands, [switch]$getnumrows)
 if ($SqlCommands.Count -ge 1) {
    $SqlCommandText = [string]::Join(";", $SqlCommands)
    try {
        $SqlCmd = New-Object Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($SqlCommandText, $SqlConnection)
        $returnvalue = $SqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        if ($getnumrows) { return $returnvalue }
    } catch {
        Write-Logfile "Error`tSQL Command failed, $($_.exception.message)"
    }
  }
}

function Run-GroupMemberExport {
param($exportmode)
 switch ($exportmode) {
    "users" {
        $dom = [ADSI]"LDAP://OU=Clients123,DC=test1,DC=test2,DC=test3"
        $query = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(samaccountname=*))"
        $table = $TableUsers
        $namecolumn = "AD_Group_Member_Name"
        $attribs = @("samaccountname")
    }
    "computers" {
        $dom = [ADSI]"LDAP://DC=test1,DC=test2,DC=test3"
        $query = "(&(objectClass=computer)(samaccountname=*))"
        $table = $TableComps
        $namecolumn = "AD_Group_Member_Device"
        $attribs = @("samaccountname", "whencreated")
    }
}
$starttime = (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime().ToString($sqldateformat)
$srch = New-Object DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher($dom, $query, $attribs)
$srch.PageSize = 1000
$srch.Sort = New-Object DirectoryServices.SortOption("sAMAccountName", [DirectoryServices.SortDirection]::Ascending)
$results = $srch.FindAll()

$count = 0
$numaccounts = $results.Count
foreach ($res in $results) {
    try {
        $objAccount = $res.GetDirectoryEntry()
        $samaccountname = $objAccount.properties["samaccountname"][0]
        $whencreated = ""
        if ($exportmode -eq "computers") { $whencreated = Get-Date ([datetime]$objAccount.properties["whencreated"][0]) -Format $sqldateformat }
        $count++
        Write-Progress "Querying accounts" $samaccountname -PercentComplete ($count * 100.0 / $numaccounts)
        $objAccount.psbase.RefreshCache("tokenGroups")
        $SIDs = $objAccount.psbase.Properties.Item("tokenGroups")
        $groups = @()
        ForEach ($Value In $SIDs) {
            $SID = New-Object System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier $Value, 0
            try {
                $Group = $SID.Translate([System.Security.Principal.NTAccount]).Value
            } catch {
                $Group = $SID.Translate([System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier]).Value
            }
            if ($groups -notcontains $Group -and $Group.Split("\")[1] -ne $samaccountname) { $groups += $Group }
        }
        Run-DBCommand @("DELETE FROM $table WHERE [$namecolumn] = '$(Esc-Quote $samaccountname)'")
        $sqlcommands = @()
        $currenttime = (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime().ToString($sqldateformat)
        if ($groups) {
            $groups | sort | foreach {
                if ($exportmode -eq "users") {
                    $sqlcommands += "INSERT INTO $table ([$namecolumn], [AD_Group_Name], [Last_Update]) VALUES ('$(Esc-Quote $samaccountname)', '$(Esc-Quote $_)', '$currenttime')"
                } else {
                    $sqlcommands += "INSERT INTO $table ([$namecolumn], [AD_Group_Name], [Last_Update], [Record_Created]) VALUES ('$(Esc-Quote $samaccountname)', '$(Esc-Quote $_)',                             '$currenttime', '$whencreated')"
                }
                if ($sqlcommands.count -ge 50) { Run-DBCommand $sqlcommands; $sqlcommands = @() }
            }
        } else {
            if ($exportmode -eq "users") {
                $sqlcommands += "INSERT INTO $table ([$namecolumn], [AD_Group_Name], [Last_Update]) VALUES ('$(Esc-Quote $samaccountname)', 'ERROR: Unable to retrieve groups',                         '$currenttime')"
            } else {
                $sqlcommands += "INSERT INTO $table ([$namecolumn], [AD_Group_Name], [Last_Update], [Record_Created]) VALUES ('$(Esc-Quote $samaccountname)', 'ERROR: Unable to retrieve                       groups', '$currenttime', '$whencreated')"
            }
        }
        Run-DBCommand $sqlcommands
    } catch {
        Write-Logfile "Error`tCommand failed while processing $exportmode`: $($objAccount.name), $($_.exception.message)"
    }
 }
 Write-Progress " " " " -Completed
 if ($count -eq $numaccounts) {
    $numdeleted = Run-DBCommand @("DELETE FROM $table WHERE [Last_Update] < '$starttime' OR [Last_Update] IS NULL") -getnumrows
    Write-Logfile "OK`tUpdates for $exportmode completed, $numdeleted old records deleted."
 }
}

function Run-GroupDescriptionExport {
$dom = [ADSI]"LDAP://DC=test1,DC=test2,DC=test3"
$query = "(&(objectClass=group)(samaccountname=*))"
$table = $TableGroups
$attribs = @("samaccountname", "displayname", "description", "whencreated", "managedby", "grouptype","distinguishedname","whenchanged")
$srch = New-Object DirectoryServices.DirectorySearcher($dom, $query, $attribs)
$srch.PageSize = 1000
$srch.Sort = New-Object DirectoryServices.SortOption("sAMAccountName", [DirectoryServices.SortDirection]::Ascending)
$results = $srch.FindAll()
$count = 0
$numgroups = $results.Count
$sqlcommands = @()
$starttime = [datetime]::Now.ToUniversalTime().ToString($sqldateformat)
foreach ($res in $results) {
    $count++
    $samaccountname = $res.properties["samaccountname"][0]
    Write-Progress "Querying accounts, $count/$numgroups" $samaccountname -PercentComplete ($count * 100.0 / $numgroups)
    $displayName = ""; if ($res.properties.contains("displayname")) { $displayName = $res.properties["displayname"][0] }
    $description = ""; if ($res.properties.contains("description")) { $description = $res.properties["description"][0] }
    $managedby   = ""; if ($res.properties.contains("managedby"))   { $managedby   = $res.properties["managedby"][0] }
    $grouptype  = ""; if ($res.properties.contains("grouptype"))   { $grouptype = $res.properties["grouptype"][0] }
    $distinguishedname  = ""; if ($res.properties.contains("distinguishedname"))   { $distinguishedname   = $res.properties["distinguishedname"][0] }
    $whencreated = ""; if ($res.properties.contains("whencreated")) { $whencreated = ([datetime]$res.properties["whencreated"][0]).ToString($sqldateformat) }
    $whenchanged = ""; if ($res.properties.contains("whenchanged")) { $whenchanged = ([datetime]$res.properties["whenchanged"][0]).ToString($sqldateformat) }
    $lastupdated = [datetime]::Now.ToUniversalTime().ToString($sqldateformat)
    $sqlcommand = "DELETE FROM $table WHERE [AD_Group_Name] = '$(Esc-Quote $samaccountname)'; "
    $sqlcommand += "INSERT INTO $table ([AD_Group_Name], [AD_Group_DisplayName], [AD_Group_Description], [Last_Update], [Managed_By],[Distinguished_Name],[Group_Category],[Created_On],           AD_Last_Modified]) VALUES ('$(Esc-Quote $samaccountname)', '$(Esc-Quote $displayName)', '$(Esc-Quote $description)', '$lastupdated', '$(Esc-Quote $managedby)', '$(Esc-Quote                   $distinguishedname)', '$grouptype', '$whencreated','$whenchanged')"

    $sqlcommands += $sqlcommand


    if ($sqlcommands.count -ge 100) { Run-DBCommand $sqlcommands; $sqlcommands = @() 
}
 }
Run-DBCommand $sqlcommands
if ($numgroups -eq $count) {
    Run-DBCommand @("DELETE FROM $table WHERE [Last_Update] <= '$starttime'")
}
Write-Progress " " " " -Completed
}

Open-Database
Run-GroupMemberExport "users"
Run-GroupMemberExport "computers"
Run-GroupDescriptionExport
Close-Database
```

Comment: That's a pretty big leap - assuming 3.0 is at fault.  If you run the script, on the same machine having trouble, but with `-version 2` parameters, do you still have an `OutOfMemoryException` occur?  If so, it's not the versioning.

Comment: I would start with commenting out some of the `Try`/`Catch` statements to check with line actually fails.

Comment: Thanks @gravitymixes. I tried -version 2 in the command statement on the same server where the script had issues before and so far it completed without any errors. I am going to run it again few more times to double check.

Comment: Subsequent tests failed so -version 2 is not a solution on it's own. What I found though is the script executes 3 functions - only the computer one throws errors - but it works fine if the 'users' function is disabled in the run. Going to try finally {
    $objAccount.Dispose() suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't have anything to do with the PowerShell version. You're just plain running out of memory. You're pulling in a lot of data, so you need to be more conscious of getting rid of that data when you're done with it.

There are a couple things you can do to clean up memory:

First, the documentation for [`DirectorySearcher.FindAll()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.directorysearcher.findall#remarks) says:

> Due to implementation restrictions, the SearchResultCollection class cannot release all of its unmanaged resources when it is garbage collected. To prevent a memory leak, you must call the Dispose method when the SearchResultCollection object is no longer needed.

So whenever you do:

```
$results = $srch.FindAll()
```

Make sure you call `$results.Dispose()` when you're done with it (at the end of the function).

Second, when you loop through the results in your `Run-GroupMemberExport` function, you're calling `$res.GetDirectoryEntry()`. Usually you can just let the garbage collector clean up `DirectoryEntry` objects, but when you're creating so many in a loop like that, the GC doesn't have time to run. This has happened to me when I've run a loop over thousands of accounts.

To solve this, you can call `Dispose()` on the `DirectoryEntry` objects yourself. Since you already have a `try`/`catch` block there, I would suggest adding a `finally` block to make sure it happens even if an error is thrown:

```
try {
    ...
} catch {
    Write-Logfile "Error`tCommand failed while processing $exportmode`: $($objAccount.name), $($_.exception.message)"
} finally {
    $objAccount.Dispose()
}
```

Actually, you could probably just not use `GetDirectoryEntry()` at all. Just ask the `DirectorySearcher` to return the other attributes you need. But if you want to still use it, then make sure you call `RefreshCache` for every attribute you need (you can put them all in one call to `RefreshCache`). If you access the `Properties` collection and ask for a value that it does not already have in cache, then it will ask AD for *every attribute with a value* - that's a lot of unnecessary data.

Comment: Thanks. I will review your suggestions to see what improvements we can make in the script but just wanted to note that the script is executed in a corporate environment using an enterprise job scheduler utility. We have dozens of servers all with same memory and CPU. However the script only fails on those servers where PowerShell has been upgraded to newer versions. It runs just fine on any server that still has the 2.0 version. That is why I thought it all had to do with version and something in the code that is not compatible.

Comment: Some promising results. I added a single instance of the 'finally' code you suggested which does $objAccount.Dispose() and the script fully completed without errors on the same server where it failed previously. All 3 functions within the script succeeded but took nearly 3 hours.

Comment: That sounds about right. If you implement the solution at the end of my answer (to not use `GetDirectoryEntry()` that should really help the time. But it will likely still take a long time regardless simply because you're going through every account.

Comment: I ran the job 3 more times and all completed from start to finish. However, when this script runs on the server with PS 3 version it takes twice as long as the same exact script on a server with PS 2 version. The servers have same specs. Any idea why? Also, on one of the runs, even though all steps completed there were 2 error instances in the logs from the "Computer" step which said: Command failed while processing computers: , Cannot index into a null array but it looks like the script ran past those and finished.

Comment: Errors in PowerShell are non-terminating by default. So a script will just continue after any error. But you may get unexpected results. Do you know the exact line where the error happened?